# Hierarchical query to determine chain of leaf's details

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data

I come forward with a problem that made me (eventually) tap as I've failed gloriously in finding a solution: considering Table_1 as my sample data source, what would be the right T-SQL code leading to the result laid out in Table_2?

Table_1: [source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmGwa.png)

Table_2: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20bCY.png)

The [HCode_EmpChain] content should reflect the '/' separated succession of unique [HCode]s associated with each [EmployeeID] identified as a [ManagerID]. Looking at Employee 11 as an example, he/she is the Manager of 12, 67 and 69, therefore their associated HCode values will be the '300251 / 421024' result sought for.

Given the significant 'real-life' number of records and an unknown hierarchy depth level, my common sense led me to a dynamic recursive CTE as the proper approach, but w/o success.

Thank you.

EDIT-> the best I was able to come up with:
[t-sql attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvN8H.png)

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the chain usually goes the other way. That is, you'd typically store the path back to an ultimate ancestor on the subordinate records. Using your sample data, EmployeeID 68 would have /722920/300251/559217/ stored in a column denoting lineage. Then if you want to query the table for "give me employees in the reporting chain of EmployeeID 11", you could either do a string-based query like (I've hardcoded it to simplify the example):

```
select * 
from dbo.Employee
where HCode_EmpChain like '/722920/%';
```

Or, if you use the hierarchyid datatype for that column

```
select child.*
from dbo.Employee as child
join dbo.Employee as parent
   on child.HCode_EmpChainIsAncestor(parent.HCode_EmpChain) = 1
where parent.EmployeeID = 11;
```